# Laravel where() vs whereLoose() methods

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

What's the difference between Laravel's `where` and `whereLoose` methods?

The documentation says:

> `where()`:
>
> The where method uses strict comparisons when checking item values.
>   Use the whereLoose method to filter using "loose" comparisons.
>
> `whereLoose()`:
>
> This method has the same signature as the where method; however, all
>   values are compared using "loose" comparisons.

In this case, what does "loose comparisons" means?

Answer (score 17):

The `where` method uses strict comparison (`===`), meaning it also checks the type of the value. If, for example, one is a string and the other a number, it won't ever match.

The `whereLoose` method uses loose comparison (`==`), meaning it won't check the type of the value. If, for example, one is a string and the other a number, it will still match if their values are the same.

```php
$collection = collect([['price' => 100], ['price' => 200]]);

$collection->where('price', '100'); // []

$collection->whereLoose('price', '100'); // [['price' => 100]]
```

You can find a table of all the differences in [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

---

**Note:** this is about to change in Laravel 5.3: the `where` method will now use loose comparison, and the `whereLoose` method will be removed. To use strict equality, you'll pass `===` as the 2nd argument:

```php
$collection = collect([['price' => 100], ['price' => 200]]);

$collection->where('price', '100'); // [['price' => 100]]

$collection->where('price', '===', '100'); // []
```

Comment: [The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) also contains details about the results of comparisons when using both operators.

Comment: Thanks guys. Is it possible that that same lines of code: $tag = ($type == 'paid') ? 0 : 1; $contracts = $user->addressbook_user->where('paid_or_not', $tag); with paid_or_not as tinyint, on two different OS(Ubuntu and Mac OS X Yosemite) but with the same mysql version, gave me two different results? Instead with whereLoose gave the same correct result? @edit: Ok I'll check the tables on php manual.

Comment: Additional: Laravel 5.3 adds a new method: `whereStrict`, so we're still able to perform strict comparisons.

Comment: Laravel 5.3 removed whereLoose() and added whereStrict(), default behavior of where() is loose now